# Using ErrorT in Haskell

Tags: haskell, error-handling, monad-transformers

I have a task to implement a function that repeatly asks user for a password and says if it is not correct. If the password is OK, then it says "Storing in database and exits". I need to use ErrorT monad transformer to tell user, that his password is incorrect, so the basic behavior looks like this

```
GHCi>runErrorT askPassword'
Enter your new password:
qwerty
Incorrect input: password is too short!
qwertyuiop
Incorrect input: password must contain some digits!
qwertyuiop123
Incorrect input: password must contain some punctuations!
qwertyuiop123!!!
Storing in database...
GHCi>
```

`askPassword'` is like

```
data PwdError = PwdError String
type PwdErrorMonad = ErrorT PwdError IO

instance Error PwdError where
    noMsg = PwdError "Unknown error"
    strMsg s = PwdError s 

instance Show PwdError where
    show (PwdError s) = show s 

askPassword' :: PwdErrorMonad ()
askPassword' = do
    liftIO $ putStrLn "Enter your new password:"
    value <- msum $ repeat getValidPassword'
    liftIO $ putStrLn "Storing in database..."
```

and `getValidPassword` looks like this:

```
getValidPassword' :: PwdErrorMonad String
getValidPassword' = do
    s <- liftIO getLine
    if length s < 8
        then throwError $ PwdError "Incorrect input: password is too short!"
        else if (not $ any isNumber s)
            then throwError $ PwdError "Incorrect input: password must contain some digits!"
            else if (not $ any isPunctuation s)
                then throwError $ PwdError "Incorrect input: password must contain some punctuations!"
                else return s
```

What am i missing here?
Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

The ErrorT datatype records errors in the `Left` field, which holds exactly one error. It cannot save each error. If you want to just "throw an error", use the IO monad and use `throw/catch` from `Control.Exception`.

If you want to use your current code, try the following:

```
withErr :: MonadError e m => (e -> m ()) -> m a -> m a
withErr f ac = catchError ac (\e -> f e >> throwError e)
```

This function applies an additional function to the error before it is rethrown. In your case, you just want to print the error:

```
askPassword' :: PwdErrorMonad ()
askPassword' = do
    liftIO $ putStrLn "Enter your new password:" 
    _ <- msum $ repeat $ withErr (liftIO . print) getValidPassword'
    liftIO $ putStrLn "Storing in database..."
```

Another approach is to use the mtl API to create a function which runs a function until it doesn't return an error.

```
try :: MonadError e m => (e -> m ()) -> m a -> m a
try h ac = go where go = catchError ac (\e -> h e >> go)
```

You can do anything with the errors, for example, collect them in a list:

```
recordErrors :: MonadError e m => m a -> m (a, [e])
recordErrors = runWriterT . try (tell . (:[])) . lift
```

However, what you want is to just print them:

```
askPassword' :: PwdErrorMonad ()
askPassword' = do
    liftIO $ putStrLn "Enter your new password:"
    _ <- try (liftIO . print) getValidPassword'  
    liftIO $ putStrLn "Storing in database..."
```